# Invoke Cortana on button click in an UWP-Application

Tags: uwp, cortana

I'm looking for a way to invoke Cortana in an UWP-Application by a button_clicked event. If the button is clicked I want Cortana to listen such as I had activated her with the "Hey Cortana" phrase or manually by clicking the microphone button. I don't want the application to always listen, it should only listen after clicking the defined button.

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really not sure ultimately what you want to use Speech for. But the Framework Element that you are looking for is `Speech Recognition`

Take a look at [Speech Recognition from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-recognition)

**Below is a sample of recognizing speech with a Listening UI.**

```
private async void StartRecognizing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    speechRecognizer = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer();
    await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
    Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(speechRecognitionResult.Text, "Text spoken");
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

**You can use this without using UI as Below**

```
Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();`
```

I would strongly Suggest you watch this video from MVA on [how to use Speech Recognition in UWP](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/integrating-cortana-in-your-apps-8487?l=20D3s5Xz_5904984382)